# How to get last/previous intent to refresh

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I am working on an online radio app demo. I've created an error `Activity` which I want to take the user to, when an error occurs. In the error page, there is a refresh `button`, which is supposed to refresh the last `Activity` where an error occurred. But I don't know how to get the `Intent` of previous `Activity` which led to the error page to get it refresh on `ButtonClick`, I only know to make it return to a particular `Activity`.

Comment: Have you tried `startActivityForResult` ?

Comment: @sneharc I have actually never heard of this before now, i am reading up on it right now and it seems like something that could work

Comment: @sneharc I just read up on it and I am not moving data back an forth. Imagine there are three activities, the first and the second activity loads the third activity which is an error page if an error occurs in either of them, so when you click on the refresh button in the third activity if the error occurred in the first activity the first activity refreshes and if the error occurs in the second activity the second activity refreshes

Comment: Check my answer. That should work!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `startActivityForResult` in both calling activities

In `MainActivity.java`

```
int REFRESH = 1;
private void startErrorActivity() {
    startActivityForResult(new Intent(this, ErrorActivity.class), REFRESH);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == REFRESH) {
        //do refresh
    }
}
```

And in `ErrorActivity.java`

```
Button button = findViewById(R.id.refreshButton);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            finish();  //this will take you back to calling activities onActivityResult method
        }
    });
```

Comment: i am sorry i really don't understand the code but i am trying to figure it out but if you could  explain better i'd appreciate it

Comment: Eg. If you're calling `ErrorActivity` from `MainActivity`, use `startActivityForResult` instead of `startActivity`. In `MainActivity` override `onActivityResult` method to refresh your activity and in `ErrorActivity` simply call `finish()` when `refresh button` is clicked.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE:
I honestly think [@sneharc](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9752602/sneharc)'s answer is better. Use that.

Try this:

```
public class ActivityA extends Activity {

    public void myFunction(){
        try{
            // something bad happens here. need to go to ErrorActivity
        }
        catch (SomeException e){
            Intent startErrorActivityIntent = new Intent(this, ErrorActivity.class);
            startErrorActivityIntent.putExtra("sourceActivity",  ActivityA.class.getSimpleName())
            startActivity(this, startErrorActivityIntent)
        }
    }

}


public class ActivityB extends Activity {

    public void myFunction(){
        try{
            // something bad happens here. need to go to ErrorActivity
        }
        catch (SomeException e){
            Intent startErrorActivityIntent = new Intent(this, ErrorActivity.class);
            startErrorActivityIntent.putExtra("sourceActivity",  ActivityB.class.getSimpleName())
            startActivity(this, startErrorActivityIntent)
        }
    }

}

public class ErrorActivity extends Activity {

    private Intent mReceivedIntent;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        mReceivedIntent = getIntent();

    }

    public void onClickRefresh(){
        String retryActivityName = mReceivedIntent.getStringExtra("sourceActivity");
        Intent retryActivityIntent = null;
        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(retryActivityName)){}
            if (retryActivityName.equalsIgnoreCase(ActivityA.class.getSimpleName()))
                retryActivityName = new Intent(this, ActivityA.class);
            if (retryActivityName.equalsIgnoreCase(ActivityB.class.getSimpleName()))
                retryActivityName = new Intent(this, ActivityB.class);
        }

        if (retryActivityIntent != null)
            startActivityForResult(this, retryActivityIntent);

    }

}
```

Comment: it has a lot of errors which i tried correcting but i could not, could you please check the third part - ErrorActivity